# Create AD users with Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to simplify the process of creating users in AD when we have to bulk add them. What I'm trying to do is to create a table in Excel with all required data that need to be added (proxyAdress, SAMaccount, user name, display name, job tittle, manager, company, etc) and based on the data to complete the blank spaces in powershell script. But I would also like to execute the script from Excel. Is this something that can be done?

Comment: executing FROM excel is  ... dangerous. it can be done, but i cannot recommend it. run the code as PoSh in a PoSh console and either save the excel file to CSV or use the ImportExcel module to read the excel file.

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey pointed out, if you have a static spreadsheet (always the same headers) then this can definitely be automated with importExcel module

Comment: The problem with importing from Excel is that I also generate random passwords in Excel for users, but after a refresh the passwords changes.

Comment: I'd suggest you copy and paste special text the passwords after you've generated them using your formula.